# Mongify - SQL connection and mongo connection not working

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongify

I am using mongify to convert MySQL data to Mongo. When I check the connection of MySQL or mongo using the commands

**mongify check sql_connection**
or
**mongify check mongo_connection**

it returns this

**Error: Database Configuration file is missing or cannot be found**

for both of them even though I have installed the gems for both and the installed mongo and MySQL from their sites too. I have also named the gems in the Gemfile too.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

In order for Mongify to do its job, it needs to know where your databases are located.
You can check your configuration by running
mongify check database.config